RHEL upgrade from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8 by using ISO + upgrade an offline
We are working on Linux RHEL 7.9 ( VM machines ) in order to upgrade RHEL version to 8.6
We are using the ISO file - rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso since RHEL7.9 machines has no direct connection to the Internet
the problem is after we run the upgrade with the following
leapp preupgrade --no-rhsm --iso /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso

after preupgrade , we get the following report
============================================================
                      REPORT OVERVIEW
============================================================

Upgrade has been inhibited due to the following problems:
    1. Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.
    2. Newest installed kernel not in use
    3. Possible problems with remote login using root account
    4. Missing required answers in the answer file

HIGH and MEDIUM severity reports:
    1. Packages available in excluded repositories will not be installed
    2. Difference in Python versions and support in RHEL 8
    3. GRUB2 core will be automatically updated during the upgrade


Reports summary:
    Errors:                      0
    Inhibitors:                  4
    HIGH severity reports:       4
    MEDIUM severity reports:     1
    LOW severity reports:        6
    INFO severity reports:       4

Before continuing consult the full report:
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.json
    A report has been generated at /var/log/leapp/leapp-report.txt

============================================================
                   END OF REPORT OVERVIEW
============================================================

before continue to the upgrade itself we fixed the following sections
1. Leapp detected loaded kernel drivers which have been removed in RHEL 8. Upgrade cannot proceed.
2. Newest installed kernel not in use
3. Possible problems with remote login using root account
4. Missing required answers in the answer file

and then we run the upgrade as:
leapp upgrade --no-rhsm --iso /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso

when upgrade finished we reboot machine but machine does not started and stuck in single user mode
what we saw is something that we not understand, and this about the accessing the iso file - /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso during boot and maybe this is part of the problem
here a screenshot during boot

why machine try to access the ISO file? and if this is part of the upgrade then why the exception about - "Cant open blockdev"


Perhaps /tmp/ is cleaned on boot?

no its still there

we not understand why after command - leapp upgrade --no-rhsm --iso /tmp/rhel-8.6-x86_64-dvd.iso is completed and doing reboot then durung boot it's still required the ISO
